# How can I control the order in which my mp3 files are played?

Tags: mp3

I ripped an audio book consisting of two CDs and copied the mp3 files to my android smartphone but they don't appear in the right order: they are sorted by track number, so the second title is the first chapter from CD 2 rather than the 2nd from CD 1.

I used k3b on linux for ripping, converted the files to mp3 using lame and copied them to my android smartphone via usb. The meta information has been obtained from CDDB. The file structure now looks like this:

```
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/cd1/01-titleA1
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/cd1/02-titleA2
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/cd1/03-titleA3

/Music/interpret/albumTitle/cd2/01-titleB1
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/cd2/02-titleB2
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/cd2/03-titleB3
```

Of course this is the order in which I want to hear them. When I close the usb connection and start the music app the new files are recognized correctly but the order is different: the directory is ignored for sorting and the titles are orderd by track number:

```
titleB1
titleA1
titleA2
titleB2
titleB3
titleA3
```

within groups of equal track numbers the order seems to be random.
In order to fix the order I renamed them likes this:

```
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/101-titleA1
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/102-titleA2
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/103-titleA3

/Music/interpret/albumTitle/201-titleB1
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/202-titleB2
/Music/interpret/albumTitle/203-titleB3
```

but the result is the same. Directory and filename seem to have to influence. I guess the order is defined by the track number taken from the headers of the mp3 files but how can I modify it? Do I have to rewrite the mp3 headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a playlist file with the correct sequence and open it on the device. It will then play in the order given in the file.

Comment: ... and k3b offers a flag to create the playlist automatically.